# Recursive function(s) to produce JSON array with all family members (ancestors and descendants) using php

Tags: php, json, recursion, mysqli

The function should receive an ID of a person as its argument and then that function goes through the entire table and finds that person's ID's father, mother, grand-father & grand-mother, wife, wife's grand-father & grand-mother, children, great-grand-children etc.

So, here's part of my MySQL table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS family (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR(250), 
  father INT(11), 
  mother INT(11), 
  husband INT(11),
  wife INT(11), 
  gender ENUM('M','F'), 
  state ENUM('Dead','Alive','Unknown')
);
```

Let me give an example: If I am *Papa Tucker* and my ID is **1**, the function should take my ID of **1** i.e. *getFamilyMembers(1)* and run through the family table and produce something as below:

```
[ 
  {"id":"10", "gen":"1", "name":"Great Papa", "father":"", "mother":"", "gender":"M", "wife":"9", "husb":""},
  {"id":"9", "gen":"1", "name":"Great Mama", "father":"", "mother":"", "gender":"F", "wife":"", "husb":"10"},
  {"id":"1", "gen":"2", "name":"Papa Tucker", "father":"10", "mother":"9", "gender":"M", "wife":"11", "husb":""},
  {"id":"11", "gen":"2", "name":"Wifey Tucker", "father":"", "mother":"", "gender":"F", "wife":"", "husb":"1"},
  {"id":"21", "gen":"2", "name":"Sis Tucker", "father":"10", "mother":"9", "gender":"F", "wife":"", "husb":""},
  {"id":"2", "gen":"3", "name":"Son Tucker", "father":"1", "mother":"11", "gender":"M", "wife":"", "husb":""}
]
```

It will pick my parents (Great Papa & Great Mama) and then attach them as the **1st generation** (that is if I have not added my parents' parents), then pick me, my wife and sister and add us as the **2nd generation**, then my son as the **3rd generation**.

A family can have as many as **10 generations** with as many as **100 members**, the function should be able to pick relatives and organize them by generations from the first to the last.

My thoughts are that, the function should be able to pick parents first and if parents are present, it re-calls itself again but this time round, it should pass parents' ID(s) and should keep doing this until it reaches the top most parents (1st generation). Once that is done, it then starts looking for the children and keeps re-calling itself looking for children until it reaches the last descendant (while doing this, it should keep storing each generation in array) and when its done,  it can display the JSON array.

Now, I'm not certain on whether to use one recursive function that searches for parents (ancestors) and children (descendants) or to use **two functions** where one searches for the ancestors and when its done, it calls the function that searches for the descendants and then displays them.

```
function getFamilyMembers($id)
{

  $fathers = array();

  if(!empty($id)){

    $QUERY  = $CONNECTION->query("SELECT * FROM family WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");

    if($QUERY->num_rows > 0){

      $RESULT = $QUERY->fetch_array();

      if(!empty($RESULT["father"])){

        array_push($fathers, $RESULT["father"]);
        getFamilyMembers($RESULT["father"]);

      }

    }

  }

  return $fathers;
}
```

I have not been able to produce any of the above **2 scenarios** code-wise. Help on this would greatly be appreciated.

---

Edit: *Papa Tucker* has a father whose ID is 10 and a mother whose ID is 9. I have attached an image for clarity.

[image: Image of Family Relation]

Comment: Some sample data would make it a lot easier to answer...

Comment: We need to see how your data looks like to help you ! When I see "Papa Tucker", you return no value in mother or father, only for "Wife". If I see the wife "Wifey Tucker", I see only "Husb" and no other value. How can you find who is the mother / father or children if you have no "link" between them in your data?

Comment: I have made an edit to show the relation between the data by adding an image

Comment: Having fixed `wife` and `husband` columns means your tables won't be able to represent divorces, second marriages, or multiple spouses. By extent, you won't be able to represent step relations either.

Comment: I do see that. That is to be handled using arrays where e.g. _wife_ field could be `['id':'status', 'id':'status', 'id':'status']` i.e. `['12':'Married', '13':'Divorced']`. However, what I need in the meantime is to be able to pick the ancestors and descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the looks of your SQL table, you should be able to run a simple `SELECT` query, which excludes the entry of the father (the entry with the id equal to 1 in this case), then order by the generation, i.e. the `"gen"-field`.

e.g. `SELECT * from family WHERE id <> 1 ORDER BY "gen"`

Am I missing something?

Comment: The generation is not stored in the table. The generation is attached by the function. The connection between the different records is the _father_ and _mother_ fields. If a user clicks a record whose ID is **2**, that ID is passed to the function. The function should run picking the parents of that person and then the siblings if any, then the grand-parents (based on the IDs of the parents) and so on. Have I been clear?

Comment: I'm sorry I see what you mean, I didn't read your second "code-block" correctly. I misread it to be a snapshot of the data in your table, but of course it's the result you want the query/function to produce..

Comment: My best bet would be to try this, like you mentioned, with recursive calls to the database. Or directly in SQL, using variables and a temporary table, something like this:

Comment: [AT]fatherId := SELECT father FROM family WHERE id = <<ID>>;
    [AT]motherId := SELECT mother FROM family WHERE id = <<ID>>;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE genList AS (SELECT * FROM family WHERE id = [AT]father OR id = [AT]mother) as gen0;
    INSERT INTO genList (SELECT * FROM family WHERE father = [AT]father OR mother = [AT]mother) as gen1;
    INSERT INTO genList (SELECT * FROM family WHERE father = <<ID>> OR mother = <<ID>>) as gen2;
    ALTER TABLE genList ADD gen TINYINT;
    UPDATE gen0 SET gen = 0;
    UPDATE gen1 SET gen = 1;
    UPDATE gen2 SET gen = 2;

Comment: You would have to replace [AT] with the 'at'-character, which i can't seem to write without SO wanting to send a message to a user.
Also, replace <<ID>> with the ID of the person you wanted the info from.
At the end you would need to query the genList- Table:
    'SELECT * FROM genList'

Comment: If I were to use that method, how do I pick the grand-parents, great-grand-parents, great-great-grand-parents etc.?

Comment: Just noticed a mistake in my query;
Syntax for variables with 'SELECT' is 'SELECT [AT]variableName := fieldName FROM table ...'

But this would return only three generations (an older and a younger one, relative from the person's id you provide).

So you need to:

- Have and repeat A function to find a parent (mother OR father) for given person
- Repeat

Comment: I have edited the question a bit to attach some PHP code to show what I'm kind of expecting the function for recursion to look like.